# Scalar found where operator expected at <script>

Tags: perl, moose

```
use Moose;

extends 'TEST::Role';

has 'name' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Str',
    default => 'me',
);
```

This works in perl 5.8.5 but not in 5.8.8.

How to resolve it?

```
String found where operator expected at B.PM line 4, near "extends 'TEST::Role'"
        (Do you need to predeclare extends?)
```

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of Perl?

Comment: why not?  5.8.9 might be worth checking, especially since it doesn't require rebuilding your XS modules.

Comment: @joe:  Yes, you can.  Use Perlbrew (http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew-0.28/lib/App/perlbrew.pm).

Comment: I cant simply go and change the version because other application depents on this version. So I cant change it

Comment: Again, yes you can.  Versions are (for the most part) backwards compatible.  Just call the script that uses your module with `/path/to/your/perl/bin/perl`

Comment: @joe, Different applications can use different versions. That's what the #! line is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get this into a failing test and post it to either the Moose mailing list, or #moose on irc.perl.org I'm sure someone can help sort out what is going on.

Please be sure to include all of the code, your package declaration is missing here (and as a first hint, I wouldn't name my package B because that collides with a core package).

Answer (score 4):

That will happen if there is no function named `extends`. Perhaps you have a broken or old Moose install? Perhaps the line before `use Moose;` is missing a semi-colon?

By the way, your file name should be `.pm`, not `.PM`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the "package xxx;" line before "use Moose;".
This worked for me.